# Py2app how to create a real Standalone app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, py2app

**Informations:**

- Python: 3.7
- Os: macOs High Sierra v 10.13.6
- IDE Pycharm

---

**First step**: make your script in python.

**Second step**: Write the setup.py file to compile the app.

**Third step**: test the app and send it to someone who did not do any installation of python..

**When my friend tries to launch the app he has an error of which I look for the solution but impossible to find a solution.**

---

**Error:**

[image: Error Image]

**Structure:**

[image: Structure Image]

Setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['rush.py']
DATA_FILES = ['index.html']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have tested the created `.app` at your computer and it was working well. What command have you used to build the `.app`?

This looks like you may have used option `-A` (`--alias`) that makes py2app NOT include the Python interpreter. `-A` should be only used for development; without this option, Python should be included in the `.app`.
[py2app documentation options](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#option-reference)